# Is there a way to check if an app has readable or writeable SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to check if a third party app installed in my devices has its `SharedPreferences` exposed through `WORLD_READABLE` or `WORLD_WRITEABLE`?

I'm using an activity from a third party and it has some settings the user can configure but I want to check if I can set them previously as needed by code.

Comment: Messing with a third party app's `SharedPreferences` would be unprofessional, IMHO. Hopefully it is not possible, as nobody with any sense creates world-accessible preferences.

Comment: Well, there are use cases for this... like opening through Intent the ZXing Barcode Scanning "library app" and setting on the flashlight beforehand.